# Issue with publishing a slidify-created presentation on GitHub

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, slidify

I'm very new to slidify. I followed a youtube video that Ramnath published back in 2012 and followed those steps closely and I was able to create slides and to publish them on my Github account (link to Ramnath video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I95GOmLc7TA)

Since I was successful doing that, I started modifying my slide and I worked on it all day. It's now complete with 47 slides and I was hoping that my simply calling publish function, just simply update my slide on my github account. When I use publish, I get this error:

```
Please set mode to selfcontained and run Slidify
This would place library files in the slide folder
making it self-contained
[1] FALSE
```

The mode is actually selfcontained and I don't know why it's not working. Should I run slidify() on my .Rmd file? I simply used publish first time. I'm a bit confused. Can someone please help me on that?

Thanks very much for your help,

Answer (score 4):

`setwd('/path/to/your/slidify/folder/')`

then run your command again.

Comment: Thanks @nml. I actually solve it by creating a new file and for some reasons I had no issue pushing that new file into Github, even though the file was an exact copy of the original one.